# Grails default rest controller

Tags: rest, grails

Is there any way to specify default version of REST controller? Lets say that we have mapping like

```
"/test"(version: '1.0.0', resources: "test", namespace: 'v1')
"/test"(version: '2.0.0', resources: "test", namespace: 'v2')
```

and versioning  is resolved with usage of http header.

If no header is specified 2.0.0 is going to be used. Is there any way to enforce version 1.0.0 in such case?

Comment: This seems like a perfectly reasonable question. Why was it down voted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grails implements semantic versioning, so whichever one is the highest version number comes first

Comment: This approach can lead to unexpected behaviour if headers are not explicitly specified. Somehow it make more sense to "ask" for new version of resource then automatically promote.

Comment: If no header is defined the highest version is selected. A version of 2.0.0 is higher semantically than 1.0.0 so Grails selects the latest version. There is nothing unexpected about that. Having said that if you want to ability to control this behaviour then you should raise a JIRA issue with a feature request (pull requests welcome)

Comment: Ok. Sorry for maybe slightly harsh tone but this is something that really  hit us on production. IOS developer hasn't specified versions in v1 of a applicaiton, backend  team didn't know that (and didn't expect that to be honest, grails docu is not clear about that or maybe we have missed something) and release of new application messed up old one (some resources were promoted to version 2). We have handled that be setting up version header in servlet filter when not set.

Comment: Nice solution, please feel free to JIRA a feature request